# Trigger Azure function via Log alert

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

**Quick context :**

I want to delete my VM(s) in a specific resource group if its CPU usage is below 30 for 1 hour.

Detailed explanation : Please refer alert-action group flow diagram (https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4gBD.png%60 ) or Below Image [Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaEz0.png)

- Resource Group -> Linux VM(s) , connected with Log analytics workspace
- Created Azure Function - Delete-VM , which written in Powershell will Delete VM
- Created Action Group (delete-Action) to trigger a mail notification and above Azure Function(Delete-VM)
- Created alert rule with signal as Log & condition as custom Log query and configured above action group to take action.

Custom Query :

`Perf | where TimeGenerated > ago(60m) | where (ObjectName == "Processor") | summarize AggregatedValue = avg(CounterValue) by Computer | where AggregatedValue < 100 | project Computer, AggregatedValue`

Issue :

- When condition breached  and alert get fired.
- Only Mail action is Triggered
- Azure Function (Delete DVSM) is not executing.

How to Trigger Azure function when Alert fired.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the [blog](https://www.cloudsma.com/2019/09/azure-monitor-alert-azure-functions/) which created by cloudsma.

#### Workaround follows

I have created the Alert Group with Email notification alert and it will trigger the Azure Function.
[image]

[image]

##### Adding Alert Rule:

[image]

Alert can be able to trigger in both Email and Azure Function

##### Alert Results

[image]
[image]